# modified blink sketch! (im a noob at arduino help!)

Tags: arduino

```
int led = 13;
int flasher = 100;

void.setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT)
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(flasher)
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(flasher)
}

if (input = "HIGH");
 {
   int flasher = 100;
 }
if (input = "LOW");
 {
   int flasher = 100;
 }
```

For some reason this code won't work... Please help!
Im an absolute noob at arduino and need lots of help!
This code is (sortof) modified blink sketch that I need to be able to run a string of code from a certain input in the serial monitor. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your conditionals within your loop (or any function for that matter)

```
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(flasher)
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(flasher)

if (input == "HIGH");
 {
   int flasher = 100;
 }
if (input == "LOW");
 {
   int flasher = 100;
 }

} // Move the bracket to here to enclose it inside the loop function
```

There is a subtle difference between what you have and what I posted. Notice the placement of the curly brackets

That said, there could be much more wrong with your code. I am assuming I cant see all of it. For example, where is your `input` variable declared and set?

There could be a number of things wrong with your code. You need to post your full sketch if you want real help

Comment: Also worth noting that the `=` operators in the `if` conditions should be `==`, and that there shouldn't be semi-colons after the conditions.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield yes thank you, I missed that

Comment: basically I want the code to be so when you type on off or flash in serial monitor it will turn on off or flash the led. if you know this it would really help if you could fix or make a new one thnx

Comment: That's not how stack overflow works. People here don't just build things for you. If you have a problem, post your code and any exceptions you see. I'm not going to build code for hardware that I can't even see. How do I know you have it configured correctly even?